# How to replicate this encoding algorithm

Tags: c, encryption, hex, encodings, strings

I am writing a helper script at work for when new people start work and need help setting up respective applications - the application will write configuration files to be loaded into the various applications. I'm not looking to get a hold of anyone's credentials through this, this is to actually hash them into something else.

The hashed string will look like this and represents an empty text field:

```
00160E0F101112131415161718191A1B1C1D1E1F202122232425262728292A0042
```

If we split this up into bytes, we will have 33 of them.

```
Bytes: 00 16 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 00 42
Index: 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32
```

Here are the results for various inputs into the text field that returns the hash:

```
"ABC0123" = 07161717176363636315161718191A1B1C1D1E1F202122232425262728292A00A3
"ABCBBBB" = 07161717171110131215161718191A1B1C1D1E1F202122232425262728292A005D
"ABCDEFGH" = 08161717171717171707161718191A1B1C1D1E1F202122232425262728292A0066
"9999999999999999999999999999999" = 1F166F6C6D6A6B686976777475727370717E7F7C7D7A7B787906070405020300B6
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" = 1A16171717171717170707070707070707171717171717171767676728292A0071
```

The conclusion I draw from this is as follows:

- The byte at index 0 represents unhashed string length, or byte length I guess is the same length.
- The byte at index 1 remains 16 through all permutations.
- Index 2 through 30 are placeholders for each character in the unhashed string, starting at 0E and increasing by 1 all up to 2A. The position seems to be involved in the conversion process as well since the same character gets different values depending on position.
- Index 31 remains 00 and I have yet to find a permutation where this changes.
- Index 32 seems to be arithmetically involved somehow but I cannot figure out how.

The application used is from 2000 something and used internally since then. It's not super important, but I am too deep in the rabbit hole to not try and see this through at this point.

This is also my first foray into decompiling with `ghidra` and I have found the place in the code that represents the GUI part of where this information is put in by the user, but I can't seem to find the encoding/conversion process *for certain* and I can't follow it along either since C was never my language unfortunately. I saw a header called `PascalString` which seems to be something like what this is but I still can't figure this out.

Comment: Can you share the binary? It'll be pretty difficult to contribute anything other than guesswork, otherwise. If not, maybe you could try comparing sequential hashes - A, B, C, etc. - the more data, the better.

Comment: I would love to but since the application is proprietary I'm not entirely sure of the legality of it.